# How do I get a sum of these numbers in array?

Tags: javascript

I want to use `for`. There are two things, one, the console.log doesn't work inside the for statement. Second, it is not summing up. code below:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
var total = 0;
for (var i= 0; numbers.length < i; i++){
    total += numbers[i];
   // console.log(total); doesn't work

}
// console.log(total); gives 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is exiting immediately because of the condition

```
for (var i = 0; numbers.length < i; i++) {
```

Because `numbers.length` (in this case) is 4, and `i` is 0, the for loop never executes.

You probably want it flipped around, to say something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 5):

Change condition in `for` should be `i < numbers.length` not `numbers.length < i`

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
var total = 0;
for (var i= 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    total += numbers[i];
}

console.log(total);
```